# Regular Expression parsing "^[\0\8]*$" - Unrecognized escape sequence \8

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will only accept 0 as the first value and 8 as the second value. I'm getting the error "parsing "^[\0\8]*$" - Unrecognized escape sequence \8."

```
[RegularExpression("^[\\0\\8]*$", ErrorMessage = "Error: Contains invalid characters")]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `^08$` ?

Comment: Why don't you use @ before your string to make it less confusing?

Comment: ^08$ seems to be working. how does it differ from ^[08]*$? Regular expressions confuse me.

Comment: @MrBones I think you mean `^08` or `^08.*$`.  @dotNet The OP says he wants to match something that starts with 0 then 8, which `^[08]*$` does not

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions at all? You could simply equate your input against the string "08" and it should do. No?

Comment: @frankhaverford `^08$` matches exactly the string "08".  Anything inside of brackets means match one of these and star means 0 or more times, so `^[08]*$` matches anything that consists of 0 or more zeros or eights.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of variants. The reason I want to treat the characters separately rather than just matching 08 is so the validation message displays after entering a single wrong character. Which should I use to accomplish this? Will upvote if posted as answer.

Comment: @frankhaverford Do you want the error message to display if they only enter "0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET doesn't like the escaped characters, which shouldn't be necessary in this case as you can avoid them by prefacing your string with a '`@`' character:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^08.*$", ErrorMessage = "Error: Contains invalid characters")]
```

This should match any string that begins with '08'.

Your present regular expression uses '[08]' which is quite different from just using '08' as the square brackets create a group that allows you to use any of the characters defined within the group. So it might accept a string that beings with '80' or '8088' etc.

Comment: I have seen `@"something"`, but not `"@something"` for raw string literal.

Comment: My apologies, it was a typo on my behalf. The '@' character should preface the quotes for the beginning of your string.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
@"^08.*"
```

Since digits are not regex special meta characters, you don't need to escape it like `\\8` or `\\0`.

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `0` Matches the digit zero. So that first character must be `0`
- `8` Matches the digit 8. So the second character must be `8`
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times. `.` is a special meta character in regex which matches any character.

`^[08].*$` matches the strings where the first character is either zero or 8. `[08]` matches a single character from the given list, ie, `0` or `8`. `^[08]*$` Matches `0` or `8`, zero or more times. Note that, `*` would repeat the previous token zero or more times and `+` would repeat the previous token one or more times.  So this would match the strings like `0808080` but not of `089`